# Integral over implicit function

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

Suppose the equation is given:

$$y^5+2y^4-7y^3+y-x=0$$

(or any other equation that cannot be expressed explicitly).

Let the solutions be implicitly given as $y=g(x)$. Is there an approach to solve the integral

$$\int\limits_0^1 x g(x) \, dx$$

either numerically or analytically?

Comment: $xy\,dx=xy\frac{dx}{dy}dy$

Answer (score 3):

Your equation isn't as random as you might think, but rather of the form $x(y)=P_n(y)$, where $P_n$

is a polynomial of the *n*-th degree. Now, $\displaystyle\int x\cdot y~dx=\int x(y)\cdot y~dx(y)=\int P_n(y)\cdot y\cdot P_n'(y)~dy$

where the new limits are the values of *y* for which $x=P_n(y)$ takes the values $0$ and $1$ respectively

with the added mention that *x* must be bijective on that interval. In this particular case, there are

three such choices. Unfortunately, only $P_n(y)=0$ can be [expressed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots) in terms of radicals. The other

is an [unsolvable quintic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Solvable_quintics). Either way, we are dealing with $F\big(y_1\big)-F\big(y_0\big)$, where *F* is a polynomial

of degree $2n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to get a general recipe. Numerically, we see from the graph of $x$ that the range $[0,1]$ implies we are interested in the "branch" that goes from $y_0\approx -0.36$ to $y_1\approx -0.58$ ($y=g(x)$ is actually multivalued). When that piece of the function $y$ is multiplied by $x$ we get something like the red line in the graph.

[image]

Its integral (orange area) can be obtained numerically (Montecarlo), eg, in Java :

```
  public static double integral(int times) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int count = 0;
    for (int t = 0; t < times; t++) {
      double x = rand.nextDouble();
      double y = -rand.nextDouble();
      y /= x;
      if (y < -1.0)
        continue;
      double x2 = Math.pow(y, 5) + 2 * Math.pow(y, 4) - 7 * Math.pow(y, 3) + y;
      if (x2 < x)
        count++;
    }
    return - count / (double) times;

  }
```

I get $I\approx 0.266$. This is not very tested, and certainly it's not optimized.